# Undefined reference to pico_dhcp_server_initiate when compiling PicoTCP for ARM mbed

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, makefile, embedded

I'm working on a project where I have to work with PicoTCP (see https://developer.mbed.org/users/daniele/code/PicoTCP/, I'm using an older version of this library). In my main.cpp file, I have the following code:

```
#include "pico_stack.h"
#include "pico_dhcp_server.h"

int main(void) {
    // create DHCP server
    struct pico_dhcpd_settings s = { };
    s.my_ip.addr = long_be(0x0a280001); /* 10.40.0.1 */
    pico_dhcp_server_initiate(&s);
}
```

The `pico_dhcp_server_initiate` function is declared in `pico_dhcp_server.h`:

```
#ifndef _INCLUDE_PICO_DHCP_SERVER
#define _INCLUDE_PICO_DHCP_SERVER

#include "pico_dhcp_common.h"
#include "pico_addressing.h"

... omitted some declarations ...

int pico_dhcp_server_initiate(struct pico_dhcpd_settings *setting);

#endif /* _INCLUDE_PICO_DHCP_SERVER */
```

And this method is implemented in `pico_dhcp_server.c`:

```
int pico_dhcp_server_initiate(struct pico_dhcpd_settings *setting)
{
    ...
}
```

When compiling the code, I get the following error: `Undefined reference to pico_dhcp_server_initiate(pico_dhcpd_settings *)`. I'm compiling with a Makefile which looks like this:

```
# This file was automagically generated by mbed.org. For more information, 
# see http://mbed.org/handbook/Exporting-to-GCC-ARM-Embedded

GCC_BIN = 
PROJECT = networking_driver_test
OBJECTS = ./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M/TARGET_M3/TOOLCHAIN_GCC/SVC_Table.o ./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M/TARGET_M3/TOOLCHAIN_GCC/HAL_CM3.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_dhcp_common.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_dhcp_client.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_http_util.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_ipfilter.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_nat.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_udp.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_igmp.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_tcp.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_simple_http.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_http_client.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_icmp4.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_ipv4.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_dhcp_server.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_dev_loop.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_http_server.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_dns_client.o ./USB_Ethernet/stack/pico_socket.o ./USB_Ethernet/stack/pico_arp.o ./USB_Ethernet/stack/pico_frame.o ./USB_Ethernet/stack/pico_device.o ./USB_Ethernet/stack/pico_tree.o ./USB_Ethernet/stack/pico_stack.o ./USB_Ethernet/stack/pico_protocol.o ./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M/rt_Semaphore.o ./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M/rt_Event.o ./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M/rt_List.o ./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M/rt_Mutex.o ./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M/HAL_CM.o ./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M/rt_Task.o ./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M/rt_CMSIS.o ./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M/rt_System.o ./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M/rt_Time.o ./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M/rt_MemBox.o ./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M/rt_Robin.o ./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M/RTX_Conf_CM.o ./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M/rt_Mailbox.o ./main.o ./USB_Ethernet/USBCDC_ECM.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_dev_mbed.o ./USB_Ethernet/modules/pico_dev_mbed_usb.o ./USBDevice/USBDevice/USBHAL_RZ_A1H.o ./USBDevice/USBDevice/USBHAL_STM32F4.o ./USBDevice/USBDevice/USBHAL_LPC17.o ./USBDevice/USBDevice/USBHAL_Maxim.o ./USBDevice/USBDevice/USBHAL_LPC11U.o ./USBDevice/USBDevice/USBHAL_LPC40.o ./USBDevice/USBDevice/USBDevice.o ./USBDevice/USBDevice/USBHAL_KL25Z.o ./USBDevice/USBMSD/USBMSD.o ./USBDevice/USBSerial/USBCDC.o ./USBDevice/USBSerial/USBSerial.o ./USBDevice/USBMIDI/USBMIDI.o ./USBDevice/USBHID/USBMouseKeyboard.o ./USBDevice/USBHID/USBKeyboard.o ./USBDevice/USBHID/USBHID.o ./USBDevice/USBHID/USBMouse.o ./USBDevice/USBAudio/USBAudio.o ./mbed-rtos/rtos/Thread.o ./mbed-rtos/rtos/Semaphore.o ./mbed-rtos/rtos/Mutex.o ./mbed-rtos/rtos/RtosTimer.o 
SYS_OBJECTS = ./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/retarget.o ./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/system_LPC17xx.o ./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/board.o ./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/cmsis_nvic.o ./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/startup_LPC17xx.o 
INCLUDE_PATHS = -I. -I./USB_Ethernet -I./USB_Ethernet/modules -I./USB_Ethernet/stack -I./USB_Ethernet/include -I./USB_Ethernet/include/arch -I./USBDevice -I./USBDevice/USBDevice -I./USBDevice/USBMSD -I./USBDevice/USBSerial -I./USBDevice/USBMIDI -I./USBDevice/USBHID -I./USBDevice/USBAudio -I./mbed-rtos -I./mbed-rtos/rtos -I./mbed-rtos/rtx -I./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M -I./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M/TARGET_M3 -I./mbed-rtos/rtx/TARGET_CORTEX_M/TARGET_M3/TOOLCHAIN_GCC -I./mbed -I./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768 -I./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM -I./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TARGET_NXP -I./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TARGET_NXP/TARGET_LPC176X -I./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TARGET_NXP/TARGET_LPC176X/TARGET_MBED_LPC1768 
LIBRARY_PATHS = -L./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM 
LIBRARIES = -lmbed 
LINKER_SCRIPT = ./mbed/TARGET_LPC1768/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/LPC1768.ld

############################################################################### 
AS      = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-as
CC      = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-gcc
CPP     = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-g++
LD      = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-gcc
OBJCOPY = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-objcopy
OBJDUMP = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-objdump
SIZE    = $(GCC_BIN)arm-none-eabi-size

CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb
CC_FLAGS = $(CPU) -c -g -fno-common -fmessage-length=0 -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fomit-frame-pointer
CC_FLAGS += -MMD -MP
CC_SYMBOLS = -DTARGET_LPC1768 -DTARGET_M3 -DTARGET_CORTEX_M -DTARGET_NXP -DTARGET_LPC176X -DTARGET_MBED_LPC1768 -DTOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM -DTOOLCHAIN_GCC -D__CORTEX_M3 -DARM_MATH_CM3 -DMBED_BUILD_TIMESTAMP=1432213479.57 -D__MBED__=1 

LD_FLAGS = $(CPU) -Wl,--gc-sections --specs=nano.specs -u _printf_float -u _scanf_float -Wl,--wrap,main
LD_FLAGS += -Wl,-Map=$(PROJECT).map,--cref
LD_SYS_LIBS = -lstdc++ -lsupc++ -lm -lc -lgcc -lnosys

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
  CC_FLAGS += -DDEBUG -O0
else
  CC_FLAGS += -DNDEBUG -Os
endif

all: $(PROJECT).bin $(PROJECT).hex 

clean:
    rm -f $(PROJECT).bin $(PROJECT).elf $(PROJECT).hex $(PROJECT).map $(PROJECT).lst $(OBJECTS) $(DEPS)

.s.o:
    $(AS) $(CPU) -o $@ $<

.c.o:
    $(CC)  $(CC_FLAGS) $(CC_SYMBOLS) -std=gnu99   $(INCLUDE_PATHS) -o $@ $<

.cpp.o:
    $(CPP) $(CC_FLAGS) $(CC_SYMBOLS) -std=gnu++98 -fno-rtti $(INCLUDE_PATHS) -o $@ $<


$(PROJECT).elf: $(OBJECTS) $(SYS_OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LD_FLAGS) -T$(LINKER_SCRIPT) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBRARIES) $(LD_SYS_LIBS) $(LIBRARIES) $(LD_SYS_LIBS)
    @echo ""
    @echo "*****"
    @echo "***** You must modify vector checksum value in *.bin and *.hex files."
    @echo "*****"
    @echo ""
    $(SIZE) $@

$(PROJECT).bin: $(PROJECT).elf
    @$(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@

$(PROJECT).hex: $(PROJECT).elf
    @$(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $< $@

$(PROJECT).lst: $(PROJECT).elf
    @$(OBJDUMP) -Sdh $< > $@

lst: $(PROJECT).lst

size:
    $(SIZE) $(PROJECT).elf

DEPS = $(OBJECTS:.o=.d) $(SYS_OBJECTS:.o=.d)
-include $(DEPS)
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error. I believe that the .c file is not being compiled somehow but I'm very new to the Makefile syntax. Could it be that there is something wrong in the makefile? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: For `DEBUG`, you might consider `CC_FLAGS += -DDEBUG -O1 -g3`. Or even `-Og` on later versions of GCC because `-Og` is meant to perform some analysis without affecting the debug experience. The `-O1` invokes basic analysis, while `-g3` adds the most debugging information, including symbolic defines.

Comment: That's interesting, I will definitely try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. In the top of the .c file, was a check whether the constant `PICO_DHCPD_SUPPORT` was defined. This was not the case what caused my .c file not to compile and thus the implementation of the function could not be found. Adding this flag to the `CC_FLAGS` setting in the makefile, fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The error you're getting is not a compiler error but a linker error.  It's complaining that it's not finding function symbols which are in the picoTCP library, which you are not linking.  You need to add a `-l<picoTCPlibGoesHere>` and `-L<path to pico TCP lib goes here>`  I don't know what the names of that library is but it should be named lib.a .  When you use it with the `-l` flag, leave off the lib and .a.  For example, if the library is named libpicotcp.a, the flag will be `-lpicotcp`.  You need to add the -l flag to your LIBRARIES and -L to LIBRARY_PATHS in your Makefile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The only .a file I see is libmbed.a which does not contain the required files. The source files for pico are located in the directory `USB_ethernet/modules`. Also, I see in the output of my compiler that `pico_dhcp_server.c` is being compiled. Any other ideas?

Comment: You might have to compile the picoTCP library.

Comment: But the other source files make use of pico and when I comment the line that gives an error, everything works fine. Also, when I invoke a function from the `pico_dhcp_client.h` class, it works which is really strange. Only when I invoke a function from the `pico_dhcp_server.h` class, it gives the compiler error.

Comment: It might be a different library which would make sense since it's server vs client.

Comment: You can also use objdump to see the symbols that are in the library. Should be trivial to grep through an entire directory of libraries. In on mobile so I can't write it now.